# Awesomium API and SDL

Tags: sdl, render, awesomium

I am using the Awesomium API for my project, but I was wondering if I can render other, non-awesomium related objects such as SDL objects into the same window that Awesomium set up for the webview?

I'm using the example code from their website tutorials
http://wiki.awesomium.com/tutorials/tutorial-2-displaying-your-first-page.html

I'd like to render something else on top of the webview, is that achievable?

Comment: Look at the `sample_webflow` sample application that comes with Awesomium, it uses SDL with OpenGL to render stuff and should give a hint on how you can do it.